# How to calculate a financial beta and theta (time decay) in R linear regression?

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, linear-regression, finance

I have the following code trying to calculate a beta (*if priceA goes up 1, then priceY goes up X*) and theta (*each month that passes priceY goes down Z*).

```
lmS9 = lm(priceY ~ months_past + priceA, data = S9)
summary(lmS9)
```

It prints the following:

```
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.172e+03  3.126e+02   3.750 0.000854 ***
months_past -5.620e+01  2.019e+01  -2.783 0.009703 ** 
priceA       1.959e-01  9.945e-03  19.701  < 2e-16 ***
```

Both are significant input variables, but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting it correctly.

In the example above `months_past` would be theta and `priceA` would be a form of beta. Is that correct? How can I create a coefficient that says if `priceA` goes up 1%, the `priceY` goes up Z?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have questions about interpreting results from a statistical model, you should ask for statistical advice at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: @MrFlick I see ty. Just posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588062/how-to-calculate-a-financial-beta-and-theta-time-decay-in-r-linear-regression